# Load shapefile with different FTypes into a GDB Feature class with different sub types

Tags: shapefile, fme-form

I have a contour shapefile with different FTypes (FTYPE_CODE) data type is text my task is to load this contours shapefile into a GDB Feature class (Contour50K) with different sub types (FeatureCode).

I just started to explore FME by downloading the trial version.

Answer (score 2):

You need first to relate your FTYPE_Code to a field (in your shape file) with [long integer. (read esri help)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_subtypes/005r00000003000000/) 
A couple of methods are to use a "distinct" or run dissolve on the ftype_code field and you will end up with a table of codes and values (your former ftype_code field).
[image: table]

Create your new feature class and associate the subtype (key in all subtype values)
Then I would use the esri simple loader found on the right click of your feature class.

1. create a new field for your subtype code of type long integer.
2. create your feature class (use your shape file to import the schema).

[image: import schema]

2. use the properties of your gdb to create the subtype.(right click)

[Use this tutorial](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0400/files/stutorial.pdf) to complete this step.
[image: create subtype]

use the simple data loader... (right click your feature class to start)

[image: simple data loader]

Now that your gdb schema is ready you can load your shape file.

Now choose to load your features into a subtype.

[image: subtype]
**(Note: you will need to load each subtype one at a time).**
You will do that with the query builder in the last stage of simple loader.
[image: query builder]

When you understand all this you can probably script all this in modelbuilder.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the reply but i wanted to work it out in FME the same process.

Comment: Please help me in sending me some example fmw to load a shape file with diff. feature types into a GDB feature class with diff. subtypes. URGENT!!!

Comment: You should specify such requirements clearly in your question so that such considerable effort (a great answer btw) is not spent on an answer you cannot use.

Comment: My sincere apologies for that..Please help me :)

Comment: If you want to accomplish this in FME. It will still have to adhere to esri data rules. I suggest attempting in esri so you know the in and outs that you could then apply to FME.

Answer (score 0):

This FMEpedia article should get you going in the right direction:

- [Working with Geodatabase Subtypes and Domains](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Working-with-Geodatabase-Subtypes-and-Domains)